# ITfRange through text services framework does not honour shiftStart shiftEnd with many applications

Tags: com, windows-xp, keyboard-events, text-services-framework

I am implementing a text service on windows XP, using microsoft text services framework. I use `ITfRange` obtained through selection. With MSOffice apps as front end, the `ITfRange->shiftStart` interface behaves correctly. But when using with many other applications like libreoffice, google chrome, firefox etc. the `ShiftStart`, does not shift the start point of selection nor does `ShiftEnd` shift the end point of selection. What could be going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's entirely possible that the applications you mention do not actually implement Text Services Framework.  If an application doesn't implement Text Services Framework, then a default implementation takes over - this is the "[transitory context](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tsfaware/archive/2007/04/25/transitory-contexts.aspx)" that I describe in my blog.  In particular, you are not allowed to manipulate the selection in a transitory context (because you're not actually talking to the application).

Comment: Thanks Eric. This really helped. I got confused because I thought if I can do text insertions then it implies that the application is TSF aware. This is not the case. I would now have a limited implementation of functionality I am attempting to write using compositions. Should serve my purpose.